# Messenger chatbot send file

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot, facebook-send-api

I'd like to send a file to the user, to do so I tried the request below, but it fails.

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#sending_attachments) are not clear about wether `is_reusable` is compulsory, but the request fails with the same error, even if I include it.

The download url works fine in a browser.

I have `https://asd.com/` whitelisted for sure.

Request:

```
 {
        "recipient": {
            "id": "157..."
        },
        "message": {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "file",
                "payload":
                    {
                        "url":
                            "https://asd.com/s3/..."
                    }
            }
        }
    };
```

Response: HTTP 500

```
 {
        "error": {
            "code": 1,
            "message": "An unknown error occurred",
            "error_subcode": 99
        }
    }
```

Comment: _“The download url works fine in a browser”_ - is it accessible by Facebook, too? (Not sure if that is necessary, but it might?) You can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to check whether Facebook can at least read the URL, or if there’s any problems regarding that. (Ignore other errors that complain about missing OG meta tags, that’s not applicable in this case.)

Comment: @CBroe It seems to be accessible. Response code: 206, Redirect path: https://asd.com/s3... to https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/... Are there any other fields that might be interesting?

Comment: Nah, that should be good enough. (It is actually able to follow the redirect and read the S3 URL as well, right? Sometimes the latter can be problematic, due to bucket configuration that tries to block “bots” or something like that.) But again, I am not sure if readability by Facebook is even a requirement ...

Comment: I just started getting a 500 error when sending attachments today as well. My chatbot has been running fine for months and no code has changed. It may just be a problem on Facebook's end. They do seem to have issues quite regularly.

Comment: @BenceGedai The URL has to point directly to the asset. The Platform will not follow a redirect.

Comment: It just got solved, the problem was at Facebook's side. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. I didn't touch the code, so probably it was an error on Facebook's side, as @Josh Cole and HTTP 500 suggested.

Recently they making quite a few breaking changes... Few days ago they broke all the web views, now the files, whats next?

I'm marking this question solved.